# Opera weird behavior, showing many alert boxes

Tags: javascript, html, opera

I am using html5 to do this basic function of pasting the same image in a canvas. It seems to work fine in Chrome and FF but when I open it in Opera, with help of localhost it goes crazy with pop up (alert like)[image: alert box]

Now it goes on like 186, 372, 558, 744, 930, 116, etc. it doesn't stop!

Can anyone figure out what's wrong? There is my code

```
imageObj.src = "Crystal-outline.gif";

var start=0; var total=150;
i=start;
for (var x=0; x <= 870;x += 30 ) {
  for (var y=0; y <= 120;y += 30 ) {
  my[i]=imageObj;
context.drawImage(my[i], x, y);
i++; 
}}
```

Image is 30x30 pixel.

Comment: This code doesn't tell us much... where is the code which display the alert box? Also, what about that "i" variable not declared with var?

Comment: my is a array in which i store images in a oder.@fredrik

Comment: @jose faeti. thats the thing there is no alert() command in my code ! but still there is alert boxes only in opera

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but try disabling user scripts, extensions and possibly even browser.js to figure out if any of those cause the `alert()`s. If you're using some JS library or code you haven't written, check the entire source code for calls to the `alert()` method. Or..try to add this to your code:

```
window.alert=function(){ try{undefined();}catch(e){opera.postError(e.stack);} }
```

which should show in the error console the entire call stack of the alert() call.